# Input loses focus when keyboard opens in iOS Browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, onfocus

Any input that I tap inside of my Swiper-Slide on the page lose focus when they keyboard opens (in Chrome and Safari). Once the keyboard is open, I can click the input and then start typing. I'm not exactly sure what's causing the problem because inputs outside of the slider work like normal.

I have an onFocus function being called by the input that doesn't fire the first time it's clicked even though the keyboard pops up. Is there some Javascript or Jquery way to force the browser to focus an input that works in iOS browsers?

Comment: Can you provide minimal code which replicates the problem?